# で particle after て form

Tags: grammar, て-form, manga, particle-で

So i was reading, and suddenly came across this sentence:

俺の力使って**で**悪魔を殺すとよぉ、すっげえ痛そうなんだわ。

Can someone explain, or provide a website that is explaining this? I wasnt able to find anything talking about this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it from the 4th episode of チェンソーマン? I initially thought this should be a typo, but since this is a popular manga and [the official site has not fixed this](https://shonenjumpplus.com/episode/10834108156724300654), I have to conclude this is not a typo.

[image: screenshot]

If it's not a typo, this で should be a particle to mark a condition. That is, the te-form (俺の力使って) is treated like a noun phrase or a "quote", and is marked with で.

This 使ってで is not incomprehensible because a te-form can be followed by でも, ですら, etc., (e.g., 何としてでも成功させる), but I think this 使ってで is at least nonstandard.

(I also thought this could be a dialectal version of 使ってて, but he is not a dialectal speaker.)

Comment: Hello Naruto, sorry to ask this but who do you refer to by using "we"? It reads like you refer to yourself, and I have seen other Japanese people on social media refer to themselves with "we" instead of "I" in their bio/profile description. Could there be a common misconception behind this?

Comment: @SevenOclock I don't find anything particularly strange about that kind of "we". It's not exclusive to Japanese people speaking English.

Comment: @SevenOclock By "we", I meant "you, I, and everyone who saw this page", but to avoid any confusion, I changed it to "I".

Comment: @Leebo Thank you for your information. It seems that I have not enough experience in English after all, because I have very rarely seen it this way. Again, please do not understand my comment as rude, I have no bad intentions. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but one last thing i wanna ask. I cant figure out the と after 殺す is it quoting particle, or conditional?

Comment: @bulgur69 It's conditional (i.e., "when(ever)").